# Joining 8 wires into one

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, outdoor

I have the cables from 9 bulbs joined into one using a screw terminal temporarily. 
What is the best thing to use to do this in a way that's waterproof and suitable for outdoor use. Whatever i use needs to be small and black, and fit on the back of a branch. I know the bulbs are over rated for the dimmer, i guess you can go over the max rating somewhat without that much of a risk of fire.

[image: 8 cables into one]

[image]

and this is the decroded piece of crap i am working on in its entirity...

[image]

Comment: You are at risk of fire, the dimmer needs to be overrated for the bulbs, not the other way around. You should also check for clearance requirements of the light sockets to be sure they aren't overheating inside the bottles, and the amperage limit of the lamp cord that you're using to be sure that it can run all 8 bulbs after that junction.

Comment: Best way to do this is to wire it in serial.

Comment: Or at least wire some of it in serial, like in pairs, this would half the size of the bus junction.

Answer (score 4):

You should be looking for something like an IP65 weatherproof junction box.

The designs vary from country to country (as do regulations of course) so it's hard to be more specific.

[image]

Ideally you want a bus type connector that has separate connection points for each wire. A single screw-terminal probably can't securely hold so many wires.

[image][image]
Example WAGO 8-way push fit connector and 5-way lever-clamp connector (400V 32A max)